# Deploy on Meteor galaxy server with bitbucket and deployment token as variable

Tags: meteor, bitbucket

Hello I want to use the automatic deploymen on bitbucket to the galaxy server with a deployment token.

For this reason I am creating a deployment token that is comitted in the repository.

https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html#deployment-token

To strenghten the security I would like to use Repository variables in bitbucket pipelines:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html

And to store the deployment token of meteor in the variables instead in file.

For the deployment we use in the command:

```
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=deployment_token.json
```

And my question is - Is there any way so that I use some variable(string) where the token is used like

```
METEOR_SESSION_DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN=$METEOR_TOKEN
```

instead to call it from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some research, after having the same problem, brought me to [this article](https://medium.com/@natestrauser/migrating-meteor-apps-from-modulus-to-galaxy-with-continuous-deployment-from-codeship-aed2044cabd9), which simply solves the problem that you can't feed meteor just the json in an env var in the following simple way:

By adding the json file content as an env var and then echoes it out into a file on deploy.

```sh
echo $METEOR_TOKEN_FILE > deploy_token.json
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=deploy_token.json
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [this article](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-i-setup-auto-deploy-from-gitlab-repo-to-meteor-galaxy/42057/2) I figured it out.

Save json settings as env variable and then in deployment procesS:

```sh
echo $DEPLOY_SESSION_FILE > deployment_token.json
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=deployment_token.json DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy --allow-superuser myApp-staging.meteorapp.com --settings config/staging/settings.json --owner username
```